# How to convert JSON column in DataFrame to "normal" columns in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame like below:

```
ABT = pd.read_excel("ABT.xlsx")
```

DATA TYPES:

- COL1 - float
- COL2 - int
- COL3 - object

  | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1.2 | 5 | {"X":"cc", "y":12} | {"A":{1,2}, "B":{3,3}"} |
  | 0.0 | 2 | {"X":"dd", "y":13} | {"A":{0,1}, "B":{2,2}"} |
  | 2.22 | 0 | {"X":"ee", "y":45} | {"A":{5,5}, "B":{1,1}"} |
  | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And I need to have something like below:

```
| COL1 | COL2| COL3               | X   | y   | A  | B 
|------|-----|--------------------|-----|-----|----------
| 1.2  | 5   | {"X":"cc", "y":12} | cc  | 12  |
| 0.0  | 2   | {"X":"dd", "y":13} | dd  | 13  |
| 2.22 | 0   | {"X":"ee", "y":45} | ee  | 45  |
| ...  | ... | ...                | ... | ... |
```

I tried to use code like below, but it does not work:
`pd.json_normalize(ABT)` because of error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

I also tried this one: `pd.io.json.json_normalize(ABT.COL3[0])` but I have error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

How can I do that in Python Pandas ? I have a problem to image how should look output for values in COL4 ?

In my real DF:
When I use `ABT.head().to_dict('list')` I have liek below:

```
{'COL1': [0.0],
 'COL2': [2],
 'COL3': [2162561990],
 'COL4': [1500.0],
 'COL5': [750.0],
 'COL6': ['{"paAccounts": {"mySector": 4, "otherSectors": 10}}'],
 'COL7': ['{"grade": "CC"}']}
```

Comment: Use `json_normalize`

Comment: mozway as I wrote in question pd.json_normalize(ABT) generate error

Comment: Then combine with `ast.literal_eval` (NB. you should provide a reproducible example as DataFrame constructor).

Comment: could you write sample of code? I do not understand :/

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor?

Comment: mozway I am not able to provide constructor I can not create sample of JSON column, but could you simply present line of code and I will implement it on my DataFrame ?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ABT.head().to_dict('list')`?

Comment: mozway, it is not the whole DF, because I have many rows but sample is like below:

Comment: {'COL1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'COL2': [2, 0, 33, 33, 2],
 'COL3': [2162561990, 2167912785, 599119703, 603482478, 2162561990],
 'COL4': [1500.0, 500.0, 3500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0],
 'COL5': [750.0, 0.0, 3500.0, 1485.0, 750.0],
 'COL6': ['{"paAccounts": {"mySector": 4, "otherSectors": 10}, "npaAccounts": {"mySector": 0, "otherSectors": 0}}

Comment: Looks like your output is truncated, can you add it as edit to the question?

Comment: mozway, I edited my question but I have a problem to even image how can look output for values in COL4 where we have nested JSON

Comment: I don't see the dictionary in your edit. I'm sorry but I can't help you without a reproducible input. Let me know if you add it, eventually.

Comment: mozway, I edited my question, at the end you have sample data after use line: ABT.head().to_dict('list')

Comment: I'm really sorry but the output you provide is invalid. This cannot be the direct output of what I requested. You must have been editing it or failed to copy a part.

Comment: mozway, You are right, I edited question again, now shoudl work good, could you check at the end of the question ?

Comment: do you have some idea mozway ? I checked the whole internet and I can not do that :/

Comment: Try: `pd.json_normalize(df['COL7'].apply(ast.literal_eval))`, for COL6, the json is invalid

Comment: I have error using your line on COL7: ValueError: malformed node or string: nan, and I edited COL6 because previously there were lack of "}"